# How to select all columns except one in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

I have a dataframe that look like this:

```
          a         b         c         d
0  0.418762  0.042369  0.869203  0.972314
1  0.991058  0.510228  0.594784  0.534366
2  0.407472  0.259811  0.396664  0.894202
3  0.726168  0.139531  0.324932  0.906575
```

How I can get all columns except `b`?

Comment: @cs95 -- The currently listed duplicate target isn't a duplicate. Despite the original title, the linked question is "Why doesn't this specific syntax work", whereas this question is a more general "What is the best way to do this". -- Add to this the difference between deleting a column from an existing DataFrame versus creating a new DataFrame with all-but-one of the columns of another.

Comment: @R.M. I'm sorry but I don't agree with the edit you've made to the title on that post, so I've rolled it back. It's true that the intent of the OP was to question the syntax, but the post has grown to address the more broad question of how to delete a column. The answers in this post are carbon copies of the highest upvoted post there. The dupe stays.

Comment: Note this question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385291/215552).

Answer (score 777, accepted):

When the columns are not a MultiIndex, `df.columns` is just an array of column names so you can do:

```
df.loc[:, df.columns != 'b']

          a         c         d
0  0.561196  0.013768  0.772827
1  0.882641  0.615396  0.075381
2  0.368824  0.651378  0.397203
3  0.788730  0.568099  0.869127
```

Comment: Not bad, but @mike's solution using `drop` is better IMO.  A bit more readable and handles multiindexes

Comment: I actually agree that @mike's solution using `drop` is better - I do think it's useful to discover that (single-level) columns are arrays you can work with, but specifically for dropping a column, `drop` is very readable and works well with complex indexes.

Comment: Thank you for this greate answer. what if I don't have a header ? how do I adrress ?

Comment: What about when you have more than 1 column to be ignored?

Comment: @Marius Does this work with multiple columns (say two)?

Comment: The trial way is

```python
 df.loc[:, (df.columns != 'b') & (df.columns != 'c')]
```

However, this grows too fast. We also can do

```python
from functools import reduce
df.loc[:, reduce(lambda x, y: x & (df.columns != y), ["b", "c"], df.columns != "z")]
```

and add as much columns we like (assuming we have no column 'z'). But, at this point, it is better to use `.drop()`.

Answer (score 441):

Don't use `ix`. It's [deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.20.0.html#whatsnew-0200-api-breaking-deprecate-ix). The most readable and idiomatic way of doing this is [`df.drop()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
>>> df.drop('b', axis=1)
          a         c         d
0  0.418762  0.869203  0.972314
1  0.991058  0.594784  0.534366
2  0.407472  0.396664  0.894202
3  0.726168  0.324932  0.906575
```

Note that by default, `.drop()` does not operate inplace; despite the ominous name, `df` is unharmed by this process. If you want to permanently remove `b` from `df`, do `df.drop('b', inplace=True)`.

`df.drop()` also accepts a list of labels, e.g. `df.drop(['a', 'b'], axis=1)` will drop column `a` and `b`.

Comment: Also works on a multiindex just like you'd expect it to.  `df.drop([('l1name', 'l2name'), 'anotherl1name'], axis=1)`.  Seems to use list vs tuple to determine if you want multiple columns (list) or referring to a multiindex (tuple).

Comment: More readable: `df.drop(columns='a')` or `df.drop(columns=['a', 'b'])`. Can also replace `columns=` with `index=`.

Comment: However this is not useful if you happen *not* to know the names of all the columns you want to drop.

Comment: Since this creates a copy and not a view/reference, you cannot modify the original dataframe by using this on the LHS of an assignment.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa Do you happen to know how to modify these selected columns within original df (such multiply all these columns with values of another column). If I modify these values I would need to tack on the dropped column on the end which doesn't seem to be best way.

Comment: @MasayoMusic The solutions using `df.loc` or masking should be able to modify the DataFrame in place.

Answer (score 228):

```
df[df.columns.difference(['b'])]

Out: 
          a         c         d
0  0.427809  0.459807  0.333869
1  0.678031  0.668346  0.645951
2  0.996573  0.673730  0.314911
3  0.786942  0.719665  0.330833
```

Comment: I like this approach as it can be used to omit more than one column.

Comment: @NischalHp df.drop can also omit more than one column df.drop(['a', 'b'], axis=1)

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this can re-arrange your columns

Comment: @ocean800 Yes that's true. You can pass `sort=False` if you want to avoid that behaviour (`df.columns.difference(['b'], sort=False)`)

Comment: This is the top one that works on a `DataFrameGroupBy`, which is what I was looking for, thanks! I used `grouped[df.columns.difference(['b'])]...`

Comment: This approach is good because it can be used with several columns and inside of a loc, if you want to update all columns except 2 for example. Moreover, it's very easy to use and the syntax is clear.

Answer (score 148):

You can use `df.columns.isin()`

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['b'])]
```

When you want to drop multiple columns, as simple as:

```
df.loc[:, ~df.columns.isin(['col1', 'col2'])]
```

Comment: This method was helpful to modify the selected columns!

Answer (score 40):

You can [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.drop.html#pandas.Index.drop) columns in index:

```
df[df.columns.drop('b')]
```

or

```
df.loc[:, df.columns.drop('b')]
```

If you need to drop multiple columns, use a list of labels instead of a single label.

Answer (score 15):

Here is another way:

```
df[[i for i in list(df.columns) if i != '<your column>']]
```

You just pass all columns to be shown except of the one you do not want.

Answer (score 9):

**Here is a one line lambda:**

```
df[map(lambda x :x not in ['b'], list(df.columns))]
```

***before***:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4), columns = list('abcd'))
df

       a           b           c           d
0   0.774951    0.079351    0.118437    0.735799
1   0.615547    0.203062    0.437672    0.912781
2   0.804140    0.708514    0.156943    0.104416
3   0.226051    0.641862    0.739839    0.434230
```

***after***:

```
df[map(lambda x :x not in ['b'], list(df.columns))]

        a          c          d
0   0.774951    0.118437    0.735799
1   0.615547    0.437672    0.912781
2   0.804140    0.156943    0.104416
3   0.226051    0.739839    0.434230
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the best way to do is the way mentioned by @Salvador Dali. Not that the others are wrong.

Because when you have a data set where you just want to select one column and put it into one variable and the rest of the columns into another for comparison or computational purposes. Then dropping the column of the data set might not help. Of course there are use cases for that as well.

```
x_cols = [x for x in data.columns if x != 'name of column to be excluded']
```

Then you can put those collection of columns in variable `x_cols` into another variable like `x_cols1` for other computation.

```
ex: x_cols1 = data[x_cols]
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is a separate answer instead of a comment / extension to Salvador's answer?

Answer (score 7):

Another slight modification to @Salvador Dali enables a list of columns to exclude:

```
df[[i for i in list(df.columns) if i not in [list_of_columns_to_exclude]]]
```

or

```
df.loc[:,[i for i in list(df.columns) if i not in [list_of_columns_to_exclude]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Similar to @Toms answer, it is also possible to select all columns except "b" without using .loc, like so:

```
df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['b'])]]
```

Comment: why, why not, would you use .loc or simply square brackets?

Answer (score 2):

I've tested speed and found that for me the `.loc` solution was the fastest

```
df_working_1.loc[:, df_working_1.columns != "market_id"] 
# 7.19 ms ± 201 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
df_working_1.drop("market_id", axis=1)
# 7.65 ms ± 136 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
df_working_1[df_working_1.columns.difference(['market_id'])]
# 7.58 ms ± 116 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

```
df_working_1[[i for i in list(df_working_1.columns) if i != 'market_id']]
# 7.57 ms ± 144 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a nice solution is with the function **filter** of pandas and **regex** (match everything except "b"):

```
df.filter(regex="^(?!b$)")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also `pop()` a column. It removes a column from a dataframe but returns it as a Series, which you assign to a value (`y` below). If you don't assign, it's just thrown away. One case where this is quite useful is to separate the target variable from the feature set in ML. For example:

```py
X = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': range(5), 'feature2': range(6,11), 'target': [0,0,0,1,1]})
y = X.pop('target')
```

It makes the following transformation:

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to drop multiple columns even if you aren't sure they exist, and works for MultiIndex columns too.

```
df.drop(columns=[x for x in ('abc', ('foo', 'bar')) if x in df.columns])
```

In this example (assuming a 2-level MultiIndex) it will drop all columns with `abc` in the first level, and it will also drop the single column `('foo', 'bar')`

I've added this answer as this is the first question that appears even when searching for MultiIndex.