# Subsetting Hierarchical Index and Hierarchical column names in Pandas (with and without indices)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am a beginner in `Python` and `Pandas`, and it has been 2 days since I opened Wes McKinney's book. So, this question might be a basic one.

I am using Anaconda distribution (Python 3.6.6) and Pandas 0.21.0. I researched the following threads (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html, `xs` function at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-xs, [Select only one index of multiindex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140771/select-only-one-index-of-multiindex-dataframe), [Selecting rows from pandas by subset of multiindex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521414/selecting-rows-from-pandas-by-subset-of-multiindex?noredirect=1&lq=1), and https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) before posting this. All of them explain how to subset `data.frame` using either hierarchical index or hierarchical column, but not both.

Here's the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan as NA

#Hierarchical index for row and column
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(36).reshape(6,6),
                 index=[['a']*2+['b']*1+['c']*1+['d']*2,
                        [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1]],
                 columns = [['Title1']*3+['Title2']*3,
                            ['A']*2+['B']*2+['C']*2])

data.index.names = ['key1','key2']
data.columns.names = ['state','color']
```

**Here are my questions:**

**Question:1** I'd like to access `key1 = a`, `key2 = 1`, `state = Title1` (column), and `color = A` (column).
After a few trial and errors, I found that this version works (**I really don't know why this works**--my hypothesis is that `data.loc['a',1]` gives an indexed `dataframe`, which is then subset...and so on):

```
data.loc['a',1].loc['Title1'].loc['A']
```

Is there a better way to subset above?

**Question:2** How do I subset the data after deleting the indices?

```
data_wo_index = data.reset_index()
```

I'm relatively comfortable with `data.table` in R. So, I thought of using http://datascience-enthusiast.com/R/pandas_datatable.html to subset the data using my `data.table` knowledge.

I tried one step at a time, but even the first step (i.e. subsetting `key1 = a` gave me an error:

```
data_wo_index[data_wo_index['key1']=='a']
```

> Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!

I don't know why Pandas is still thinking that there is multi-index. I have already reset it.

**Question:3** If I run `data.columns` command, I get the following output:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['Title1', 'Title2'], ['A', 'B', 'C']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]],
           names=['state', 'color'])
```

It seems to me that column names are also indexes. I am saying this because I see `MultiIndex` class, which is what I see if I run `data.index`:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], [1, 2, 3]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0]],
           names=['key1', 'key2'])
```

I am unsure why column names are also on object of `MultiIndex` class. If they are indeed an object of `MultiIndex` class, then why do we need to set aside a few columns (e.g. `key1` and `key2` in our example above) as indices, meaning why can't we just use column-based indices? (As a comparison, in `data.table` in R, we can setkey to whatever columns we want.)

**Question 4** *Why* are column names an object of `MultiIndex` class? It will be great if someone can offer a theoretical treatment for this.

As a beginner, I'd really appreciate your thoughts. I have spent 3-4 hours researching this topic and have hit a dead-end.

Comment: Why is this tagged R?

Comment: I'm very sorry about this. I tagged it because I did compare `R - data.table` with `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `MultiIndex`'s can be tricky to work with, so it's worth considering whether they actually provide enough benefit for what you're actually doing (in terms of speed/organisation) to make those hassles worthwhile.

To answer your question 1, you can subset a `MultiIndex`ed dataframe by providing tuples of the keys you want for each axis. So you first example subset can be done as:

```
# We want to use ":" to get all the states, but can't just
#   have ":" by itself due to Python's syntax rules
# So pandas provides the IndexSlice object to wrap it in
slicer = pd.IndexSlice
data.loc[('a', 1), (slicer[:], 'A')]
```

Which gives:

```
state   color
Title1  A        0
        A        1
Name: (a, 1), dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am using indexes because I read somewhere that `join` and `merge` are faster with indexes. While McKinney has also written that one can do `join` and `merge` using columns. Could you please offer alternatives to indexing?

Comment: The alternative to indexing is basically to leave everything in plain columns, like R does (when not using `data.table`). Joins may be slower than the indexed versions, but it can be easier to work with, especially if you're used to R.

Comment: Thank you once again. Final q: While I haven't run benchmarks between `pandas` and `data.table`, from your experience,  will `pandas` be slower than `data.table` in R?

Answer (score 1):

Wow seems like a lot of questions ..

Q1 Multiple index I will recommend `IndexSlice`

```
data.loc[pd.IndexSlice['a',1],pd.IndexSlice['Title1','A']]
Out[410]: 
state   color
Title1  A        0
        A        1
```

Q2 when you reset the index for this complete data frame it will have some issue , I do not think in `R` you can do that without `ftable`

Here is the way doing with pandas

```
data_wo_index.loc[np.concatenate(data_wo_index.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice['key1',:]].values=='a')]
Out[434]: 
state key1 key2 Title1       Title2        
color                A  A  B      B   C   C
0        a    1      0  1  2      3   4   5
1        a    2      6  7  8      9  10  11
```

Q3 I think the `column` and `index` multiple level offer 4 dimension, yes you can using one columns or index to represent all  just do `stack`

```
data.stack()
Out[436]: 
state            Title1  Title2
key1 key2 color                
a    1    A           0       3
          B           1       4
          C           2       5
     2    A           6       9
          B           7      10
          C           8      11
b    3    A          12      15
          B          13      16
          C          14      17
c    1    A          18      21
          B          19      22
          C          20      23
d    3    A          24      27
          B          25      28
          C          26      29
     1    A          30      33
          B          31      34
          C          32      35
```

Q4 `MultiIndex`  is one of type for index , and `pandas` treat `index` and `columns` to index type

For example

```
df.index # index but just different type of index 
Out[441]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype='int64')
df.columns # index as well 
Out[442]: Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I sincerely appreciate it. Could you please give me some resource how I can understand and create `data_wo_index.loc[np.concatenate(data_wo_index.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice['key1',:]].values=='a')]` query that you have posted for Q2?

Comment: @watchtower you can try with Pandas Cookbook