# Calculating in dataframe - why am I getting KeyError here?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "City": ["NY", "NY", "LA", "LA", "MIA", "MIA"],
        "Mall": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"],
        "Category": ["Milk", "Egg", "Egg", "Beef", "Egg", "Orange"],
        "Price": [5, 10, 4, 9, 6, 11]
    }
)
df
df = df.set_index(['City', 'Mall', 'Category'])
df
```

It looks like:

```
                            Price
City    Mall    Category    
NY      A       Milk        5
                Egg         10
LA      B       Egg         4
                Beef        9
MIA     C       Egg         6
                Orange      11
```

(The data must be in multi-index form)

At first I tried the following calculation and it worked out perfectly:

```
df['Price_diff'] = df['Price'].groupby(level=[0,1]).pct_change(periods=-1)
df

>>>
                           Price    Price_diff
City    Mall    Category        
NY      A       Milk       5        -0.500000
                Egg        10       NaN
LA      B       Egg        4        -0.555556
                Beef       9        NaN
MIA     C       Egg        6        -0.454545
                Orange     11       NaN
```

Then, for each city, mall, and category, I wanted to compare the price difference with egg. I wrote:

```
df['Price_diff'] = df['Price'].sub(df['Price'].where(df['Category'].eq('Egg')).groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('first'))
```

This is when I got the error message:

```
KeyError: 'Category'
```

Why is this happening and what should I do?

Expected outcome:

```
                            Price   Price_diff
City    Mall    Category    
NY      A       Milk        5       -5
                Egg         10      0   
LA      B       Egg         4       0
                Beef        9       5
MIA     C       Egg         6       0
                Orange      11      5
```

Comment: `df['Category]` won't work because category is set as an index not a column. Probably this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28140771/select-only-one-index-of-multiindex-dataframe
for selecting only one index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. So as `Category` is an index in the dataframe, it cannot be accessed by using `df["Category"]`. Instead, you could use `df.index.get_level_values(2)`. The code is as follows:

```
df['Price_diff'] = df['Price'].sub(df['Price'].where(df.index.get_level_values(2) == 'Egg').groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('first'))
df
```

The output is:

```
                    Price  Price_diff
City Mall Category                   
NY   A    Milk          5        -5.0
          Egg          10         0.0
LA   B    Egg           4         0.0
          Beef          9         5.0
MIA  C    Egg           6         0.0
          Orange       11         5.0
```